# How to integrate this expression? I failed to integrate it, though I have also shown my approach.

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate $$\int \frac{\sqrt{\int x dx}}{\sqrt{\int (x^{2}+\frac{9}{4}) dx}}dx$$ ? I am trying this question by integrating the numerator first. So, the integration of the numerator will be $\sqrt{\frac{x^{2}}{2}+C}$. Now I can't understand how to further simplify the numerator. Now to simplify the denominator we have to substitute first , $x$ $=$ $\frac{3}{2}×tan\theta$. So, $dx$ $=$ $\frac{3}{2}× (sec\theta)^{2}×d\theta$. So, finally the denominator will become $\frac{3×\sqrt{3}}{2×\sqrt{2}}× \sqrt{\int{(sec\theta)^{4}d\theta}}$. But I can't proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: Where does this question appear? It appears to be a lot of work if we have to take into consideration all the possible constants of integration $C_1$,$C_2$ in the numerator *and* denominator. On the other hand, if we are allowed to take this constants 0 the integral becomes something of the form $\int \sqrt{x}/\sqrt{x^2 + a}$ which also does not seem that trivial to me

Answer (score 4):

It is not too bad if both integration constants are zero.
$$I=\int\frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{9
   x}{4}}}\,dx=\int\sqrt{ \frac{6 x}{4 x^2+27}}\,dx$$

Using the Gaussian hpergeometric function
$$I=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{9} \,\,  x^{3/2} \,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{7}{4};-\frac{4
   x^2}{27}\right)$$

With the integration constant, after simplication
$$J=\int \sqrt{\frac{6x^2+a}{4x^3+27x +b}   }\,dx$$ becomes a nightmare.

If $a=0$ and $b\ne 0$, there is an ugly antiderivative in terms of elliptic integrals of the first and second kinds.

If $a\neq0$ and $b=0$, there is a simple expression which involves  the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

If $a\neq0$ and $b\neq 0$, there is probably no solution except using series.